# current_user on front_end with ng-token-auth and devise_token_auth

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ionic-framework

I have a service:

```
.factory('FacilityUser', function($resource) {
  return $resource("http://localhost:3000/api/facility_users/:facility_user_id/patients");
 });
```

I am using ng-token-auth with devise-token-auth.  For the facility_user_id, I am trying to pass in the id of the current user, but I can't figure out how to access the current user on the front-end.  How do I do this?

Comment: I am stuck with this same issue...Have you found any solution that you can share...@Philip7899

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure it's the best way: $auth.validateUser().$$state.value.id

Comment: thanks for replying!!!can you point me to any resource or links that might help me in understanding this...I am not able to find much documentation on `ng-token-auth`...thanks a lot @Philip7899